# How to View Several Excel Rows in Python

Tags: python, excel

So, I am trying to create a Python program that reads a password protected excel file. The program is intended to report any names expiring between 90 and 105 days. The problem I am running into right now is getting the program to read multiple rows. I've been using import xlrd. I was hoping that 'counter' would change the row being read, but only the first row is being read.

Edit: Solved. I was able to use the code below to get my program to display entries that are expiring within my time field.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

today = date.today()
ninety_Days = (date.today()+timedelta(days=90))
hundred_Days = (date.today()+timedelta(days=105))

hundred_Days = '%s-%s-%s' % (hundred_Days.month, hundred_Days.day, 
hundred_Days.year)
ninety_Days = '%s-%s-%s' % (ninety_Days.month, ninety_Days.day, 
ninety_Days.year)

wkbk = pd.read_excel('Practice Inventory.xlsx', 'Sheet1')
mask = (wkbk['Expiration'] >= ninety_Days) & (wkbk['Expiration'] <= 
hundred_Days)
wkbk = wkbk.loc[mask]
print(wkbk)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Practice Inventory.xlsx')

new_df = df[df['days to expiration'] >= 90]
final_df = pd.concat([df[df['days to expiration'] <= 120], new_df]
```

The final_df will hold all the rows with days of expiration greater than 90 and less than 120.